# Is there a fastest way to detect which varibles declared but not being used?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I just moved about 1000 lines of codes out of my `create.vue` to mixins/script1, mixins/script2, mixins/script3 and so on.

I import

```
import './mixins/script1'
import './mixins/script2'
import './mixins/script3'
```

I realized I have so much `data() { ...`

[image]

Is there a way to detect what is the unused variables?

I want to clean them out

Comment: What is the definition of `unused` variables ? the properties which have empty string/array/object ?

Comment: declared but never call or use it

Comment: we can use `es-lint` to get the errors but not sure is there any way to remove the unused variables/properties or not.

Comment: No. This is the problem with writing this kind of code. The most you can be done is to make exact word matches in the project for all the keys. If it's not found, it's certainly unused

Comment: @EstusFlask  Do you have a script or want to get me started on how to do that ? right now, I have been using cmd + D to select all , and cmd F to find within a file.  But that is not scalable at all. If you know any better tools/IDE extensions please let me know.

Comment: No, I don't have any specific in mind, if this were supposed to be reusable, I'd make it Node script. You can collect two lists of keynames from mixins and the rest of files with regex tool like grep, findstr, etc, the first will be `key1 key2 ...`, then it's concatenated to `\bkey1|key2|...\b` regex to retrieve the second list. And then compare these lists in excel or JS script in a console.